# Update and insert from one table with multiple same ID rows but different column attributes to second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to update the records from one table to another table and if there are new records then insert those records. In this case, the new records are having the same ID but different column attributes. When I am running the update and insert query, it's only considering the last entry from table one. It seems that it's overwriting the data in table 2. How to approach this? I would like to add 2 additional records in table 2 even though the Premise_ID is the same for them.

1st table

```
SELECT Premise_ID, Division, InstallationType
FROM [GIS_NewJersey].[sde].[SAP_Load]
WHERE Premise_ID = '8000004592'
```

Result:

[image]

2nd Table

```
SELECT Premise_ID, Division, InstallationType
FROM [GIS_NewJersey].[sde].[PREMISE]
WHERE Premise_ID = '8000004592'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Show us the update and insert queries. And include the DDL for the tables to help everyone else understand what your primary and natural keys are. I also suggest you stop using 3 part names without a very good reason - your connection should determine the database to use for your object (table) references.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`MERGE` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql)

```
WITH Source AS (
    SELECT Premise_ID, Division, InstallationType
    FROM sde.SAP_Load
    WHERE Premise_ID = '8000004592'
),
Target AS (
    SELECT Premise_ID, Division, InstallationType
    FROM sde.PRtsqlEMISE
    WHERE Premise_ID = '8000004592'
)
MERGE Target t
USING Source s
  ON t.Premise_ID = s.Premise_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    Division = s.Division,
    InstallationType = s.InstallationType
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (Premise_ID, Division, InstallationType)
    VALUES (s.Premise_ID, s.Division, s.InstallationType)
;
```

Remove the two `WHERE` filters in order to match all `Premise_ID` rows

Comment: This is what i am getting After running the query...."The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows."

Comment: OK so you need the `ON` clause to be a unique match. Unfortunately, you haven't given me your schema so I've no idea what you need

Comment: How to provide ON clause based on 2 columns?   something like this ON t.Premise_ID.InstallationType = s.Premise_ID.InstallationType

Comment: Just use `AND` like this `ON t.Premise_ID = s.Premise_ID AND t..InstallationType = s.InstallationType `

Comment: I have only one unique ID. Is there any way to get around this error "The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows"

Comment: Clearly the `ON` clause is not resulting in unique joins between source and target. You need to refines the `ON` as the error message says